zephyr central NUS
I have two nrf52840 dongles and I want to get them to communicate with each other. It is worth noting I am very new to embedded programming, so be patient with me. So far I have gotten both the peripheral and central to connect to each other. I have also gotten the peripheral to communicate with NUS with my phone's bluetooth terminal app- I can send messages to my dongle and the dongle responds by sending a message back and blinking the on board LED. However, even though the central and peripheral are connected to one another I cannot get them to exchange messages. I am assuming setting up NUS on the central is not the same as on the peripheral, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set up NUS on the central.
I tried setting up NUS on the central the same way I set it up on the peripheral. I was expecting the two to send messages back and forth.
For the Peripheral I used the peripheral_nus example from the zephyr project example and was able to communicate with my phones bluetooth terminal
https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/tree/d2a45222504fcfffb40b05bbc349e8c3766ae19c/samples/bluetooth/peripheral_nus
Here is my central code:
#include <zephyr/types.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/printk.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/services/nus.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/conn.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/uuid.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/gatt.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/byteorder.h>

#define DEVICE_NAME     CONFIG_BT_DEVICE_NAME
#define DEVICE_NAME_LEN (sizeof(DEVICE_NAME) - 1)

static void start_scan(void);

static struct bt_conn *default_conn;

static const bt_addr_le_t peripheral_addr = {
    .type = BT_ADDR_LE_RANDOM,
    .a.val = {0xC8, 0xF8, 0x6C, 0x27, 0xEB, 0x10}
};

// vvv
static void notif_enabled(bool enabled, void *ctx)
{
    ARG_UNUSED(ctx);
    printk("%s() - %s\n", __func__, (enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"));
}

static void received(struct bt_conn *conn, const void *data, uint16_t len, void *ctx)
{
    char message[CONFIG_BT_L2CAP_TX_MTU + 1] = "";
    int err;

    ARG_UNUSED(conn);
    ARG_UNUSED(ctx);

    memcpy(message, data, MIN(sizeof(message) - 1, len));
    printk("%s() - Len: %d, Message: %s\n", __func__, len, message);
}

struct bt_nus_cb nus_listener = {
    .notif_enabled = notif_enabled,    
    .received = received,
};
// ^^^

static void device_found(const bt_addr_le_t *addr, int8_t rssi, uint8_t type,
                         struct net_buf_simple *ad)
{
    char addr_str[BT_ADDR_LE_STR_LEN];
    int err;

    if (default_conn) {
        return;
    }

    if (type != BT_GAP_ADV_TYPE_ADV_IND && type != BT_GAP_ADV_TYPE_ADV_DIRECT_IND) {
        return;
    }

    bt_addr_le_to_str(addr, addr_str, sizeof(addr_str));
    printk("Device found: %s (RSSI %d)\n", addr_str, rssi);

    if (rssi < -50) {
        return;
    }

    if (bt_le_scan_stop()) {
        return;
    }

    err = bt_conn_le_create(addr, BT_CONN_LE_CREATE_CONN, BT_LE_CONN_PARAM_DEFAULT, &default_conn);
    if (err) {
        printk("Create conn to %s failed (%d)\n", addr_str, err);
        start_scan();
    }
}

static void start_scan(void)
{
    int err;

    err = bt_le_scan_start(BT_LE_SCAN_ACTIVE, device_found);
    if (err) {
        printk("Scanning failed to start (err %d)\n", err);
        return;
    }

    printk("Scanning successfully started\n");
}

static void connected(struct bt_conn *conn, uint8_t err)
{
    char addr[BT_ADDR_LE_STR_LEN];

    bt_addr_le_to_str(bt_conn_get_dst(conn), addr, sizeof(addr));

    if (err) {
        printk("Failed to connect to %s (%u)\n", addr, err);

        bt_conn_unref(default_conn);
        default_conn = NULL;

        start_scan();
        return;
    }

    if (conn != default_conn) {
        return;
    }

    printk("Connected: %s\n", addr);

    // Register NUS callbacks
    err = bt_nus_cb_register(&nus_listener, NULL);
    if (err) {
        printk("Failed to register NUS callback: %d\n", err);
    }
}

static void disconnected(struct bt_conn *conn, uint8_t reason)
{
    char addr[BT_ADDR_LE_STR_LEN];

    if (conn != default_conn) {
        return;
    }

    bt_addr_le_to_str(bt_conn_get_dst(conn), addr, sizeof(addr));

    printk("Disconnected: %s (reason 0x%02x)\n", addr, reason);

    bt_conn_unref(default_conn);
    default_conn = NULL;

    start_scan();
}

BT_CONN_CB_DEFINE(conn_callbacks) = {
    .connected = connected,
    .disconnected = disconnected,
};

int main(void)
{
    int err;

    printk("Initialization begin\n");

    err = bt_enable(NULL);
    if (err) {
        printk("Bluetooth init failed (err %d)\n", err);
        return 0;
    }

    printk("Bluetooth initialized\n");

    start_scan();

    err = bt_nus_cb_register(&nus_listener, NULL);
    if (err) {
        printk("Failed to register NUS callback: %d\n", err);
        return err;
    }   

    }

    while (true) {
        k_sleep(K_SECONDS(1));
        if (default_conn) {
            const char *message = "hello\n";
            err = bt_nus_send(NULL, message, strlen(message));
            if (err < 0 && err != -EAGAIN && err != -ENOTCONN) {
            return err;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


Nordic Semiconductor has it's own SDK, which is basically an extension to the Zephyr RTOS, named the nRF Connect SDK. In this one, they some additional samples, that are not in Zephyr. Among these are Bluetooth UART Peripheral and Central samples. See https://docs.nordicsemi.com/bundle/ncs-latest/page/nrf/samples/bl.html.
You still can use Zephyr RTOS if you want of course, but maybe these samples can be a good inspiration to doing what you want if so.
Disclaimer: I work for Nordic Semiconductor technical support.
If you are new, maybe our guides over at https://academy.nordicsemi.com/ will be useful to you? These are specific for the nRF Connect SDK, but most of the things you learn are equally applicable to the Zephyr RTOS as well.
